# Youtube url parameter ?playlist=[video_id's] no longer working

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

On my website, we have product pages where employees can put in youtube video id's into the CMS. Those id's are saved into the database, and later pulled out in the array $videos.

```
    <? php
    $youtube_url[0] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/?rel=0&modestbranding=1&playlist=";
    $youtube_url[0] .= implode(",", $videos);
    ?>
    <iframe width="580" height="315" src=<?= $youtube_url[0] ?> frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This creates a an hoc playlist out of the Youtube IDs listed after playlist= and had been working properly for nearly a year until sometime within the last week or so. Did something change? Is the ?playlist= parameter broken?

Comment: Have you, by any chance, asked YouTube?

Comment: I went to their site and tried for support and it said to create a stack exchange post with the youtube-iframe-api tag. This is apparently the only way they wanted hear about the issue. see here https://developers.google.com/youtube/players/support

Answer (score 2):

It works fine if you define the first id as the video:

Like: https://www.youtube.com/embed/qYodWEKCuGg?playlist=uOtdsJKsDc0,b-IEVMwBEfo

**Code:**

```
<?php
$videos = [
    'qYodWEKCuGg',
    'uOtdsJKsDc0',
    'b-IEVMwBEfo'
];

$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$videos[0].'?playlist=';
array_shift($videos);
$url .= implode(",", $videos);
?>

<iframe width="580" height="315" src="<?= $url ?>" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

whilst this won't work:

https://www.youtube.com/embed?playlist=qYodWEKCuGg,uOtdsJKsDc0,b-IEVMwBEfo

Comment: Hm. Thats odd because it worked that way for a year now. I remember assuming that i needed it to be this way when i was building it but was surprised when i tried with no video id and just the playlist parameter. I guess i can go through and edit everything but its frustrating that it would suddenly stop working.